# How to use a different sorting parameter with two different citation styles (Biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

After many trials (based on questions/answers) I cannot get the expected result. (I am with TexStudio + LiveTex + Ubuntu)

I need to print my cited references in `numeric` style and `sorting=none` (must be sorted as the appear in the document) and then print a group of non cited references by a keyword but in `authoryear` style and `sorting=ydnt` (must be sorted descending by year)

As you know if I use `ydnt` in the `\usepackage[]{biblatex}` the numeric style will be not in numeric order as they appear in the document.

The next pic show how I get at the moment:

[image: The result I have so far]

my code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[
    style = numeric, 
    backend=biber,
    % sorting=ydnt,
    maxnames=1
    ]{biblatex} 

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibenvironment{mycumstomstyle}
% The following definition is copied from authortitle.bbx/authoryear.bbx
    {\list %authoryear
        {}
        {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

\addbibresource{papers.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{State of Art}
Research institutes \cite{Adjiri2019}
the reent publications first. \cite{Ak2016a} 

\printbibliography[category=cited]

\appendix
\section{Appendix: Literature research}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=mycumstomstyle, title = Machine Learning for vertical wind speed extrapolation, keyword=ML.WS.vertical, notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

The `papers.bib` is in [here](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/8uvJLyZ5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one wants to use different sorting schemas, the sorting schema should be specified by introducing a new ref context, so for the specific case, one needs `\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]` just before the second `\printbibliography`. So the code should look like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[
    style = numeric, 
    backend=biber,
    % sorting=ydnt,
    maxnames=1
    ]{biblatex} 

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibenvironment{mycumstomstyle}
% The following definition is copied from authortitle.bbx/authoryear.bbx
    {\list %authoryear
        {}
        {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

\addbibresource{papers.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{State of Art}
Research institutes \cite{Adjiri2019}
the reent publications first. \cite{Ak2016a} 

\printbibliography[category=cited]

\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
\appendix
\section{Appendix: Literature research}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=mycumstomstyle, title = Machine Learning for vertical wind speed extrapolation, keyword=ML.WS.vertical, notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```